# Traefik instance cannot resolve TLS handshake, how to reconfigure from v1.7.17 to v2.0.2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, caddy

I was previously using Traefik 1.7.17, I saw v2 has been out and tried the Go binary of converting files from 1.7.17 to v2, but it failed on certain configs. I Googled everywhere for similar questions and looked at the documentation, but nothing I try to put together has worked with v2.
I was starting to understand how Traefik v2 works with routers, middlewares, and services, but I just got more confused reading other forums and posts.

Previously in v1.7.17, I had the dashboard on a subdomain with a redirect to https with ACME Let's Encrypt, which was used throughout. Below are my files to hopefully get Caddy to reverse proxy a NUXT server that I had working with 1.7.17.

What I'm trying to do is have Traefik dashboard on port 8080 with https at my specified domain.
Have Traefik handle the caddynuxt server and caddynuxt server is listening on transparent to the actual nuxt client (I had this working in 1.7.17). I thought dynamic routing from Traefik in v2 would handle it, but I am not sure.

I would appreciate the correct way to do this and pointers. I'm also using DigitalOcean, if that helps. I am using Docker (not in swarm at the moment, would like to use Kubernetes soon).

The acme.json file is empty because I'm using staging as you see below, but I do have an acme account that I was using for production... After I can get v2 to work.

Traefik docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:   
   traefik:
      image: traefik:v2.0.2
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
        - "8080:8080"
      # expose:
      #   - 8080
      networks:
        - unicausalpublic
        - unicausalnetwork
        - unicausalapi
        - unicausaldevelopment
        - stageunicausaldevelopment
      environment:
        - DO_AUTH_TOKEN=NOPE
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
        #- ./acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme.json
        - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=unicausalpublic"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`monitor.unicausal.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
        # - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
        # - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=dashadmin"
        # - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls"
        # - "traefik.http.middlewares.dashadmin.basicauth.users=yeaboii:ignore."

networks:
  unicausalpublic:
    external: true   
  unicausalnetwork:
    external: true
  unicausalapi:
    external: true
  unicausaldevelopment:
    external: true
  # stage network may be moved to dedicated staging environment
  stageunicausaldevelopment:
    external: true
```

My Traefik v2 toml:

```
# Typically, a router replaces a frontend, and a service assumes 
# the role of a backend, with each router referring to a service.

[global]
  checkNewVersion = true
  sendAnonymousUsage = true


[log]
  level = "DEBUG" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC


# static configuration
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.traefik]
    address = ":8080"


[providers]
  providersThrottleDuration = "5s"
  [providers.docker]
    watch = true
    endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedbydefault = false
    # swarmModeRefreshSeconds = "15s"
  # [providers.file]
  #   filename = "/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"

[api]
  insecure = false
  dashboard = true
  debug = false


# ref: https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/migration/v1-to-v2/
# Routers
[http.routers]
  # below is dashboard router only
  [http.routers.api]
    rule = "Host(`monitor.unicausal.com`)"
    # rule = "Host(`traefik.docker.localhost`)"
    entrypoints = ["websecure"]
    service="api@internal"
    middlewares = ["dashadmin"]
    [http.routers.api.tls]
      certResolver = "letsencrypt"
      [[http.routers.api.tls.domains]]
        main = "unicausal.com"
        sans = ["*.unicausal.com"]


[http.middlewares]
  # Redirect to https
  [http.middlewares.redirectwebsecure.redirectScheme]
    scheme = "websecure"
  [http.middlewares.dashadmin.basicauth]
    users = [
      "yeaboii:IGNORE",
    ]


# you name your certResolvers.[name].type
[certificatesResolvers]
  [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt]
    [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme]
      email = "yeaboii@gmail.com"
      #caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/yeaboii"
      caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      storage = "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
        # [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnsChallenge]
        #   provider = "digitalocean"
        #   delayBeforeCheck = 0
        [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpChallenge]
          entryPoint = "web"
```

Below is my Traefik debug log:

```
Starting v202_traefik_1 ... done
Attaching to v202_traefik_1
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from file: /etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="Traefik version 2.0.2 built on 2019-10-09T19:26:05Z"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded {\"global\":{\"checkNewVersion\":true,\"sendAnonymousUsage\":true},\"serversTransport\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200},\"entryPoints\":{\"traefik\":{\"address\":\":8080\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{}},\"web\":{\"address\":\":80\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{}},\"websecure\":{\"address\":\":443\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{}}},\"providers\":{\"providersThrottleDuration\":5000000000,\"docker\":{\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15000000000}},\"api\":{\"dashboard\":true},\"log\":{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"format\":\"common\"},\"certificatesResolvers\":{\"letsencrypt\":{\"acme\":{\"email\":\"yeaboiii@gmail.com\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"/letsencrypt/acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"httpChallenge\":{\"entryPoint\":\"web\"}}}}}"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="Stats collection is enabled."
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="Many thanks for contributing to Traefik's improvement by allowing us to receive anonymous information from your configuration."
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="Help us improve Traefik by leaving this feature on :)"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="More details on: https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/contributing/data-collection/"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=error msg="Unable to add ACME provider to the providers list: unable to get ACME account: permissions 644 for /letsencrypt/acme.json are too open, please use 600"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="Starting provider aggregator.ProviderAggregator {}"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=traefik
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=web
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=websecure
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15000000000}"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 18.09.1 (API 1.39)" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" container=devnuxt-unicausal-client-c20aa52d24acdd5e94357785abb36e6d760d79eb7ba7d64ba9879b46125ade73 providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"api\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"websecure\"],\"service\":\"traefik-v202\",\"rule\":\"Host(`monitor.unicausal.com`)\",\"tls\":{\"certResolver\":\"letsencrypt\"}},\"devcaddynuxt\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\"],\"middlewares\":[\"file.redirectwebsecure\"],\"service\":\"devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client\",\"rule\":\"Host(`stage.unicausal.com`)\",\"tls\":{\"certResolver\":\"letsencrypt\"}},\"websecure\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"websecure\"],\"service\":\"devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client\",\"rule\":\"Host(`stage.unicausal.com`)\",\"tls\":{}}},\"services\":{\"devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.18.0.3:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}},\"traefik-v202\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.18.0.2:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}}},\"tcp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining entryPointName=websecure routerName=websecure@docker serviceName=devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" routerName=websecure@docker serviceName=devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client entryPointName=websecure
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.18.0.3:80" entryPointName=websecure routerName=websecure@docker serviceName=devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client serverName=0
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client" routerName=websecure@docker middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=websecure
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining entryPointName=websecure routerName=api@docker serviceName=traefik-v202
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=websecure routerName=api@docker serviceName=traefik-v202
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.18.0.2:80" serverName=0 entryPointName=websecure routerName=api@docker serviceName=traefik-v202
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware traefik-v202" entryPointName=websecure routerName=api@docker middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=websecure middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining serviceName=devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client entryPointName=web routerName=devcaddynuxt@docker
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" routerName=devcaddynuxt@docker serviceName=devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client entryPointName=web
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.18.0.3:80" routerName=devcaddynuxt@docker serviceName=devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client serverName=0 entryPointName=web
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware devcaddynuxt-unicausal-client" entryPointName=web routerName=devcaddynuxt@docker middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=error msg="middleware \"file.redirectwebsecure@docker\" does not exist" entryPointName=web routerName=devcaddynuxt@docker
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=error msg="the router devcaddynuxt uses a non-existent resolver: letsencrypt"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:33:22Z" level=error msg="the router api uses a non-existent resolver: letsencrypt"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:13Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"monitor.unicausal.com\""
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:13Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"monitor.unicausal.com\""
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:13Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 108.246.102.12:56299: remote error: tls: unknown certificate"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:13Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 108.246.102.12:56300: remote error: tls: unknown certificate"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:15Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"stage.unicausal.com\""
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:15Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"stage.unicausal.com\""
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:15Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 108.246.102.12:56321: read tcp 172.23.0.2:443->108.246.102.12:56321: read: connection reset by peer"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:15Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 108.246.102.12:56322: remote error: tls: unknown certificate"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:56Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"monitor.unicausal.com\""
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:56Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"monitor.unicausal.com\""
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:56Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 108.246.102.12:56542: read tcp 172.23.0.2:443->108.246.102.12:56542: read: connection reset by peer"
traefik_1  | time="2019-10-13T18:34:56Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 108.246.102.12:56543: read tcp 172.23.0.2:443->108.246.102.12:56543: read: connection reset by peer"
```

Now this is a different docker container. This is for client-side/front-end:

I wasn't sure about the labels in this one. Where is it good to define them, in the docker file or the traefik toml file? Also how do I handle redirects from http to https here?

docker compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  # For Nuxt server
  devcaddynuxt:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./configdocker/staging/devCaddyNuxt-Dockerfile
    environment:
      - "ACME_AGREE=true"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - unicausalapi
      - unicausalpublic
      - unicausalnetwork
      - unicausaldevelopment
      - stageunicausaldevelopment
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=unicausalpublic"
      - "traefik.http.routers.devcaddynuxt.rule=Host(`stage.unicausal.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.devcaddynuxt.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.devcaddynuxt.middlewares=file.redirectwebsecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.rule=Host(`stage.unicausal.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.websecure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.devcaddynuxt.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      # - "traefik.http.services.devcaddynuxt.loadbalancer.server.port=443"


  devnuxt:
    build: ./unicausal-client-nuxt/
    restart: always
    networks:
      - unicausalpublic
      - unicausaldevelopment
      - stageunicausaldevelopment
    ports:
      - "8004:80"
    command:
      "npm run start"

networks:
   unicausalpublic:
      external: true
   unicausalnetwork:
      external: true
   unicausalapi:
      external: true
   unicausaldevelopment:
      external: true
   stageunicausaldevelopment:
      external: true
```

The Caddyfile config (the Dockerfile just loads the image pretty much)

```
:80 {
    proxy / devnuxt:8004 {
        transparent
    }
    log stdout
    errors stdout
}
```

Also I'm aware of

```
level=error msg="Unable to add ACME provider to the providers list: unable to get ACME account: permissions 644 for /letsencrypt/acme.json are too open, please use 600"
```

I have tried changing permissions correctly to 600 many times, but still, get the TLS handshake error regardless.

Thank you for your time, if I'm missing more info let me know. I really want to learn this, but I feel like the documentation is lacking clear examples for what I want, and I'm a devops beginner.